# Maven Jetty Plugin - Servlets Aren't Working

Tags: java, servlets, maven, jetty

I have the following servlet coded in `/src/main/java/examples/web/SimpleServlet.java`:

```
package examples.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void goGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = res.getWriter();
        writer.println("SimpleServlet Executed!");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

And the following web.xml defined in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SimpleServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>examples.web.SimpleServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SimpleServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/simpleservlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And the following pom.xml defined in `/pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>examples.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>simple-webapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>simple-webapp Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>simple-webapp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

When I run `mvn jetty:run` I get output indicating that everything is working correctly. When I load `localhost:8080/simple-webapp` I am served `src/main/webapp/index.jsp`, so I know Jetty is at least partially working.

**And now for the question:** Although I am able to get to `index.jsp`, I cannot get to `/simple-webapp/SimpleServlet` -- I just get a 404 error from Jetty. Because of my configuration in `web.xml`, I was expecting to see `SimpleServlet Executed!` from `SimpleServlet`. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the relevant output from `mvn jetty:run`:

```
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: simple-webapp Maven Webapp
[INFO] Webapp source directory = C:\Users\Ken\Workspace\Eclipse\Maven\simple-webapp\src\main\webapp
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO] Classes = C:\Users\Ken\Workspace\Eclipse\Maven\simple-webapp\target\classes
2011-11-23 16:59:56.220:INFO::Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
[INFO] Context path = /simple-webapp
[INFO] Tmp directory =  determined at runtime
[INFO] Web defaults = org/mortbay/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file = C:\Users\Ken\Workspace\Eclipse\Maven\simple-webapp\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml
[INFO] Webapp directory = C:\Users\Ken\Workspace\Eclipse\Maven\simple-webapp\src\main\webapp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URLs are case-sensitive. The defined URL pattern does not match the value that you are requesting:

```
<url-pattern>/simpleservlet</url-pattern>
```

Try http://localhost:8080/simple-webapp/simpleservlet (lowercase servlet name).

Comment: When I do that I get the error `HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL`. Although it's a different issue entirely, any ideas about that one?